# Cannot find module 'store/actions/user' from 'login-form.js'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I have this **jest** configuration

```
"jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest",
      ".*": "./tests/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./tests/enzyme_setup"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "shared"
    ]
  }
```

and I'm using react redux and I'm getting this error:

Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'store/actions/user' from 'login-form.js'

  2 | import * as PropTypes from 'prop-types';
  3 |
> 4 | import { userActionsShape } from 'store/actions/user';
  5 | import Scss from './scss/index.scss'
  6 |
  7 | export class LoginFormComponent extends React.Component {

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:194:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/components/auth/login-form/login-form.js:4:13)
```

can someone please help me?
I'm stuck on this

Comment: Run the command by setting `NODE_PATH` to the location of store folder.

For example:
`NODE_PATH=./src jest`

where src contains the store folder

Comment: doesnt solved...

Comment: i added this
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "^store/actions/user$": "<rootDir>/src/app/components/auth/login-form/index.js"
    }

Comment: but im getting this error

Answer (score 0):

```
"transform": {
      "\\.js$": "./__tests__/custom-transformer.js",
      "^.+\\.scss$": "jest-css-modules-transform",
      ".*": "./__tests__/preprocessor.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node",
      "scss"
    ],
```

and

npm install --save --dev jest-css-modules-transform
it works for me
Many thanks Carlos Vieira

Answer (score 0):

i already solved
i put this config jest

```
{
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",

      "^.+\\.jsx$": "<rootDir>/__tests__/enzyme_setup.js",
      "^.+\\.scss$": "jest-css-modules-transform"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node",
      "scss"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "./__tests__/enzyme_setup"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "bower_components",
      "shared"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^store/actions/user$": "<rootDir>/src/app/components/auth/login-form/index.js",
      "^models/user$": "<rootDir>/src/app/components/user/user-info/index.js",
      "^store$": "<rootDir>/src/app/store/index.js",
      "^initial-state$": "<rootDir>/src/app/store/initial-state.js"
    },
    "testRegex": "/__tests__/.*.test.(js|ts|tsx)?$"
  }
```

done!
it works for me
many thanks
Carlos Vieira